# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rmagick'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
rails s
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rmagick'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/harshamv/Sites/platehopper/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

When i am trying to run rails server am getting the above error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer is out of date. I ran into this issue on Mac OSX (El Capitan) and ImageMagick (6.9.4). I resolved it by reverting back to an older version of ImageMagick and reinstalling rmagick as follows:

```
brew uninstall --force imagemagick
```

Note: I had to use `--force` because of multiple, old versions installed. You could also just run the command multiple times if you're worried about the `--force` option.

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/master/imagemagick-ruby186.rb
gem uninstall rmagick
gem install rmagick -v 2.15.0
```

Comment: Just for clarification (and in case people come across this in future years) by latest I am guessing you are referring to El Capitan and Imagemagick 6.9.4-3?

Comment: You can do `brew uninstall --force imagemagick` to uninstall all imagemagick versions too.

Comment: Updated to reflect the additions suggested by RustComet and rbatta - thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i was deploying my rails application, this is what i had to do to fix it.

First make sure you remove imageMagick from your project, execute following command in your terminal

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
```

Our use force if you get an error.

```
brew uninstall -f imagemagick
```

Then install the version 2.14.0, this is the last working one i found.

```
gem install rmagick -v 2.14.0
```

Make sure you add the version number to your Gemfile, before you use bundle update, if you run into a error remove your Gemfile.lock, so bundle can reset any strange dependencies.

```
gem 'rmagick', '2.14.0'
```

If i'm correct it should be working again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, version of ImageMagick installed with RMagick is not supportable follow this [link](http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/)